# HTTPie prompts for password

Tags: httpie

I am using HTTPie to make edgegrid authenticated calls to a set of REST APIs, but httpie always asks for password which hinders my ability to make calls in a shell script. The password is my localhost/system password, which after inputing, the command executes fine.

~/Desktop/DevOps/HTTPie/apiscripts-wip/tech_jam/casemanagement$ ./pull_cases.sh 
**http: password for techjam@localhost:**

Question -> how do avoid this? Is there some issue with my environment set up?

Comment: How does the `http` invocation in `pull_cases.sh` look like?

Comment: http -a techjam :"/case-management/v2/cases?duration=30&type=company-active" > cases.json

The config.json looks like as below 
{
    "__meta__": {
        "about": "HTTPie configuration file",
        "help": "https://httpie.org/doc#config",
        "httpie": "1.0.2"
    },
    "default_options": [
        "--auth-type=edgegrid",
        "-adefault",
        "--timeout=300"
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

> `--auth, -a`
>
> Pass a `username:password` pair as the argument. Or, if you only specify a username (`-a username`), you'll be prompted for the password before the request is sent.
>
> https://httpie.org/doc#authentication

So you just need to update your script to include the password:

```sh
http -A edgegrid -a techjam:YOURPASSWORD --timeout=300 ':/case-management/v2/cases?duration=30&type=company-active'
```

(Btw, you don't need to—and probably don't even want to—change the default options in the config to include `--auth-type`, etc. The command above contains all those options so you can just `rm ~/.httpie/config.json`.)